# App Crash due to lateinit of late getting current location with GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

---

I am trying to get the current location, however the app crash because the app found lateinit property has not been initialized because the app hasn't yet to ask for user permission of GPS to get current location.

---

Below are the code :

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback{

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var currentLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val permissionCode = 101

    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    private val MasjidZahir = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(6.1046784,100.3716608)
    private val Jabil = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(5.3267065,100.2820637)
    private val TARUCKL = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(3.2162302,101.7267724)
    private val TARUCPG = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(5.4532105,100.2826858)
    private val MARINA = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(1.3149938,103.890498)

    private var locationArrayList: ArrayList<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        fusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
        fetchLocation()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val map = binding.mapView

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.onResume()
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)

        locationArrayList = ArrayList()

        locationArrayList!!.add(MasjidZahir)
        locationArrayList!!.add(Jabil)
        locationArrayList!!.add(TARUCKL)
        locationArrayList!!.add(TARUCPG)
        locationArrayList!!.add(MARINA)
    }

    private fun fetchLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), permissionCode)
            return
        }

        val task = fusedLocationProvider.lastLocation
        task.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if(location != null){
                currentLocation = location
                Toast.makeText(this.context, currentLocation.latitude.toString() + " "
                        + currentLocation.longitude.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
    }


    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {

        googleMap = map
        for(i in locationArrayList!!.indices){
            googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(locationArrayList!![i]).title("Marker $i"))

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18.0f))
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locationArrayList!![i]))
        }


    // Here is the problem
        val latLng = com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location")
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f))
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode){
            permissionCode -> if (grantResults.isEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                fetchLocation()
            }
        }
    }
```

---

How do I prevent the app to crash, or let the onMapReady() to wait for the permission request from user first before putting current location marker to the map?

---

Comment: here currentLocation property is not initialized

Answer (score 1):

Two things

Dont use `lateinit` in this case because you are trying to access a property before you have something in which there is no guarantee you will even get

instead make it nullable

```
private var currentLocation: Location? = null
```

then null check before you access it

```
if(currentLocation != null){

}
```

Second move where you put the map marker on the map to when you actually get the location instead of in `onMapReady` and you should also make your `googleMap` property nullable because you could run into a case where the location is received before the map is ready so you are either setting the location in your onMapReady if you have a location already OR setting it in when you get the location because the map was ready before you got the location

Comment: You'll need something like `currentLocation?.let {}`, or precede the if statement with `val currentLocation = currentLocation`, since it's a property.